How do I display contact sub types in a View without the underscores?
I'm using CiviCRM 5.62.1, CiviRules 2.49, Drupal 7.98
I have created a View which creates a table with organisation name and contact sub type, grouped by region. However, on the display, the contact sub types come up with underscores instead of spaces eg. Arts_Stream_of_Sanctuary (see pic below). Is there any way of getting the display to put a space instead of an underscore?
I figured out that I can create a conditional that works with one phrase ie. change 'Arts_Stream_of_Sanctuary' to 'Arts Stream of Sanctuary' but I want to do that for all the variations without creating a new conditional / column for each


Have you used drupal views or Civi search kit?

I have used Drupal Views
